# iOS6 XCode4.6.2 Passing Row Number via a Segue

Tags: ios6, xcode4, nsindexpath

If I pass data via a Seque to another View Controller, e.g.

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mySequeIdentifier"]) {
         NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
         RecipientViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
         destViewController.intPassedRow = indexPath.row;
    }
 }
```

THis passes the correct row number but...

I get an error saying "Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'int' from 'int'."

If they are both Ints then what have I done wrong?

Comment: They are not both `int`s. You probably declared your `intPassedRow` as a pointer to an `int`, while in reality you are passing it an `int`.

Comment: I'm sure you're spot on - how do I reconcile this?

Comment: Please post the exact declaration of your property `intPassedRow` to verify my suspicion, then I can tell you what to change.

Comment: @property int *passedRowNumber;                                 NSString *strpassedRowNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",passedRowNumber];                                    The second line generates the yellow warning, the numbers are correct but clearly it's not correct. Many thanks.

Comment: The * before passesRowNumber indicates that it is a pointer. Remove that and it should work.

Comment: That worked - I will learn from this - many thanks!